# How to get elements that have prefixes in an event with Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I have a function that has this in it.

```
var obj = app.loadComponent("guiItem", {"prefix": sItems + "-"});
```

Inside the component `guiItem` are 2 text boxes (tbx1, tbx2)

I currently have a absolute panel where instances of `guiItem` can be added, to ensure that tbx1 and tbx2 are unique I prefix the added instance of `guiItem` each time (see code line above).

The problem:
When tbx1 is changed I need the text of tbx2 to change, but I do not know how this can be done with Google Script.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question more clearly ? Specifically, what are the multiple items you are talking about ? How are these related to the two text boxes.

Comment: Ok yeah, I will make an edit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var obj = app.loadComponent("guiItem", {"prefix": sItems + "-"});
/* Store your prefix somewhere */
CacheService.getPrivateCache().put('prefix',sItems + '-' , 300);
/* .... */
var hdl = app.createServerHandler('handleTbx1Change').addCallbackElement('your_panel_object');
app.getElementById(sItems + '-' + 'tbx1').addChangeHandler(hdl); 


function handleTbx1Change(e){
  var prefix = CacheService.getPrivateCache().get('prefix');
  app.getElementById(prefix + 'tbx2').setText(e.parameter.tbx1); // assuming setName('tbx1') on tbx1
```

Thats the rough sketch. You'll need to do some fine tuning but that piece of code should show the way